# flex doesn't include changes on new runs

Tags: apache-flex, browser

I have a problem with flex . sometimes when I change my application and run it , my changes doesn't appear in the application , and I have to change my browser setting in flex to see changes on other browsers , and after doing it for a while and solving the problem permanently , other browsers will do the same and don't show my changes . anyone has the same problem or know how to solve this ?
thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As exus noted it probably your browser cache. Clear you browser cache and run the app again.

If that doesn't do it, do a "clean" build from FlashBuilder. On occassion, application files don't get overwritten.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

I had same problem once. I did setup a new browser and set cache to 0. Now it works